# Multithreaded calculation loading data from multiple files. How to utilize and synchronize StreamReaders in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, streamreader

Please if anything is unclear in my question, let me know how to make it better. I am new on this forum, so apologies in advance for any mistakes.

I am running a calculation on a number of financial instruments. For each of them I have two separate files - one containing records of trades on a given market, second the current state of the order book (bidask sizes and prices). Since the files are large, I need to load one line of the datafile per calculation. For the same reason, merging the files together is not a good idea as well.

My question is, how to use two StreamReaders (or any other way?) to peform the following calculation:

1. load both lines
2. decide which came first according to its timestamp
3. perform calculation on the first and save the second to a temp
4. load another line of the calculated file
5. compare with the temp (step 2)
6. repeat

For one file it is quite trivial. The calculation looks as follows:

```
string[] ListOfRawData = Directory.GetFiles(...);
Parallel.ForEach
        (
        ListOfRawData,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
        (FileName) =>
        {
            SupportMethods Support = new SupportMethods(FileName);
            List<Calculation> CalculationInstances = new List<Calculation>();
            using (StreamReader DataFile = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while (!DataFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    // Determine whether the line is new trade or an orderbook update
                    Support.TradeOrUpdate(DataFile);

                    switch (Support.IsTrade)
                    {
                        case false:
                            foreach (Calculation ActualCalculation in CalculationInstances)
                            {
                                ActualCalculation.DOMUpdateMethod(DMUpdate, Support);
                            }
                            break;
                        case true:
                            foreach (Calculation ActualCalculation in CalculationInstances)
                            {
                                ActualCalculation.TradeUpdateMethod(TradeUpdate, Support);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
      }
      );
```

I want to perform the same calculation, however now loading from two separate files.

During my search I read that using two streamreaders requires two separate threads - is it so? Would it be a problem, since I run the aforementioned calculation simultaneously for 8 different instruments on multiple threads with Parallel.ForEach?

Both files are identified by a timestamp as follows:

Trades file:

```
02-JAN-2007,08:21:13.173,+1,Trade,40.6,1000,40.6800 (...)
02-JAN-2007,08:21:16.379,+1,Trade,40.6,130,40.6800 (...)
```

Orderbook file:

```
02-JAN-2007,08:21:13.274,+1,Market Depth,40.6,4000,1,40.7,4731,3, (...)
02-JAN-2007,08:21:17.345,+1,Market Depth,40.6,3870,1,40.7,4731,3, (...)
```

Any ideas or links would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The part of code I am interested in is between the "using Streamreader" and "swich" statement. The parallel.foreach may be confusing, i added it simply for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Try this link code: http://www.splinter.com.au/sorting-enormous-files-using-a-c-external-mer/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a merge join algorithm. It takes two sorted sequences and merges them into one in constant memory. You can find such an algorithm on the web if you don't want to do it yourself.

The code would look something like:

```
IEnumerable<...> src1 = GetSource1();
IEnumerable<...> src2 = GetSource2();
IEnumerable<...> merged = Merge(src1, src2, x => x.GetTimeStamp(), x => x.GetTimeStamp());
merged
 .AsParallel()
 .ForEach(x => PerformUpdate(x));
```

This makes reading the files single-threaded and processing the joined results multi-threaded.

Comment: Thanks for the comment usr. If I understood correctly, what this algorithm does (in layman terms) is that it loads both files, merges them into one and then performs calculationl. Correct? If so, then this is not what I am looking for, as I mentioned in my question. The files are large and I do not want to pre-load them. Instead, loading one line per calculation, then moving to the next. THe only trouble I have is with synchronization of the streamreaders - in other words, a way of telling the program which datafile to load the line from in the next step.

Comment: The part of code I am interested in is between the "using Streamreader" and "swich" statement. The parallel.foreach may be confusing, i added it simply for the sake of completeness.

Comment: It works in a streaming fashion on sorted data. If you want to compare/merge two phonebooks you only need to look at one line at a time and advance front to back.

Comment: In any case there is no need for two threads for the two readers. Probably, you should use File.EnumerateLines to have the files represented as streams.